# Is there a way to remove connection: keep-alive from axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, keep-alive

Axios is assigned to Vue.prototype which is directly imported from node_modules like:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Vue from "vue"

Vue.prototype.axios = axios;
```

Every time the browser sends a request, `connection: keep-alive` is available.

Is there a way to remove the header?

The default header availabe in `axios.defaults.headers.common` is

```
{
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [documentation for the Connection-header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) it is classified as as "[Forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name)".

What this basically means is that they are handled by the browser and can't be changed by code.

This is also true for a bunch of other headers such as Referer and Cookie (the whole list is available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name).

Comment: Hi, Karl. Is there any way to send requests with header `Connection: close` from chrome? I'd like to tell the server not to reuse a connection.

Comment: As it says in the documentation, "Forbidden headers" are handled by the browser and can't be changed from scripts. So it is not possible.